# Correlation between two scores where one of scores has a confidence interval

Tags: python, correlation, confidence-interval

`scipy.stats` module has several metrics like `pearsonr`, `spearmanr` to compute the correlation between two set of scores. In my case, one set of the scores are actually mean of multiple scores and so I have a confidence interval for each score. Is there any correlation metric that can exploit the confidence interval and come up with a better score?